# Ubuntu Landscape Openstack install kilo neutron-l3-agent: unrecognized service

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, openstack-neutron

I am running a Ubuntu Landscape Openstack install version kilo. I need to restart my neutron-l3-agent, but every time I try I get this error **neutron-l3-agent: unrecognized service**. I am using this command **sudo service neutron-l3-agent restart**. What am I missing here? Also, there is no L3 log in the /var/log/neutron directory.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Here is a screen shot of my neutron agent list and the error I get. !http://i1292.photobucket.com/albums/b576/brotherchris81/neutronlist_zpstscgq7s9.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the

http://docs.openstack.org/kilo/install-guide/install/apt/content/neutron-network-node.html

To install the Networking components

```
# apt-get install neutron-plugin-ml2 neutron-plugin-openvswitch-agent \
  neutron-l3-agent neutron-dhcp-agent neutron-metadata-agent
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have all these installed, and I can restart all the other services but not neutron-l3-agent for some reason.